# Integration test with Spring-context doesn't receive RabbitMQ messages

Tags: rabbitmq, testcontainers, spring-context

## RabbitMQ MessageConsumer doesn't receive the published message

I'm writing an integration test which should received a message from a queue and do the processing. But the consumer simply doesn't receive the message.

When I manually inject the dependencies - *without Spring context*, things works fine. But when I use SpringContext, the consumer doesn't receive the message.

The `SpringInfraConfig.class` loads values from environment variables. To 'emule' the the environment I'm usging the class `EnvironmentVariables` from [this library](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules/). The env variables are loaded fine - checked running debug.

**NOTE** when I mention *without SpringContext works fine*, I wasn't using the Environment Library too.

To publish the message into RabbitMQ queue, I'm doing it 'manually' on test method. The message is published fine. I wrote a consming test code before call my real testing class. It's a simple raw consumer overriding `DefaultConsumer#handleDelivery` with a `sysout` to print the incoming message. Works.

When I test using my real testing class - `MessageConsumerServiceImpl.class` it just log starting consuming from queue and the test ends.

Something pretty weird occurs when I debug and step into all methods - the message is received and in the middle of processing it ends up without completing all calls - *the test just stops*, no error are threw too.

Another weird thing is - enabling the RabbitMQ management plugin, there are no queues, exchange,  channels or even a connection open. I checked this in debug running while stoped into a break-point.

### SpringConfig class

```
@Import({SpringCoreConfig.class})
@ComponentScan({"br.com.fulltime.fullarm.fullcam.integration.infra",     "br.com.fulltime.fullarm.cross.cutting", "br.com.fulltime.fullarm.infrastructure.commons"})
@Configuration
public class SpringInfraConfig {

@Bean
public FInfraSettings getFInfraSettings() {
    Map<String, String> fInfraMap = new HashMap<>();
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_RABBIT_HOST", "f_infra_rabbit_host");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_EXCHANGE", "f_infra_exchange");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_QUEUE", "f_infra_queue");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_PROCESS_ID", "f_infra_process_id");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_DESCRIPTION", "f_infra_description");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_TEXT", "f_infra_text");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_TAG", "f_infra_tag");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_WARNING_TIME", "f_infra_warning_time");
    fInfraMap.put("F_INFRA_CRITICAL_TIME", "f_infra_critical_time");

    return new FInfraSettings(
            getEnv("f_infra_run", "false").asBoolean(),
            getEnv("f_infra_ka_time", "1").asInt(),
            fInfraMap);
}

@Bean
public ApplicationSettings getApplicationSettings() {
    return new ApplicationSettings(
            getEnv("process_name", "FullArm-FullCam Integration").asString(),
            getEnv("process_version", "DEFAULT-1.0.0").asString());
}

@Bean
public PushoverSettings getPushoverSettings() {
    return new PushoverSettings(
            getEnv("pushover_api", "invalido").asString(),
            getEnv("pushover_user_id", "invalido").asString(),
            getEnv("pushover_run", "false").asBoolean());

}

@Bean
public RabbitMQSettings getRabbitMQSettings() {
    return new RabbitMQSettings(
            new RabbitConnectionInfo(
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_host", "127.0.0.1").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_port", "5672").asInt(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_virtual_host", "/").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_username", "guest").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_password", "guest").asString()),
            new RabbitConnectionInfo(
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_fullcam_host", "127.0.0.1").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_fullcam_port", "5672").asInt(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_fullcam_virtual_host", "/").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_fullcam_username", "guest").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_fullcam_password", "guest").asString()),
            new RabbitQueueInfo(
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_queue", "fcomQueConsumerFullCam").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_exc", "fcomExcConsumer").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_rk", "fcomRKConsumerFullCam").asString()),
            new RabbitQueueInfo(
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_queue", "foo").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_exc", "foo").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_rk", "foo").asString()),
            new RabbitQueueInfo(
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_publish_fullcam_queue", "fullcamRequest").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_publish_fullcam_exc", "fullcamRequestExc").asString(),
                    getEnv("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_rk", "fullcamRequestRK").asString()));
}

@Bean
public RedisSettings getRedisSettings() {
    return new RedisSettings(
            getEnv("redis_host", "localhost").asString(),
            getEnv("redis_port", "6379").asInt(),
            getEnv("redis_password", "123456").asString());
}

@Bean
public Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        return RabbitConnectionFactory.create(getRabbitMQSettings().getConnectionInfo());
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        throw new ShutdownException(e);
    }
}

@Bean
public Logging getLogging() {
    return new DefaultLogger();
}
```

### MessageConsumerServiceImpl class

```
@Component
public class MessageConsumerServiceImpl implements MessageConsumerService {

private final Connection rabbitMQConnection;
private final MessageConsumerFactory consumerFactory;
private final RabbitMQSettings mqSettings;
private final ShutdownService shutdownService;
private final Logging logger;

@Inject
public MessageConsumerServiceImpl(Connection rabbitMQConnection,
                                  MessageConsumerFactory consumerFactory,
                                  RabbitMQSettings mqSettings,
                                  ShutdownService shutdownService,
                                  Logging logger) {
    this.rabbitMQConnection = rabbitMQConnection;
    this.consumerFactory = consumerFactory;
    this.mqSettings = mqSettings;
    this.shutdownService = shutdownService;
    this.logger = logger;
}

@Override
public void startListening() {
    try {
        RabbitQueueInfo commandQueInfo = mqSettings.getRabbitMQFullArmConsumerQueue();
        final String queue = commandQueInfo.getQueue();

        Channel channel = rabbitMQConnection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(queue, true, false, false, null);
        MessageConsumer commandConsumer = consumerFactory.create(channel);

        logger.info("[MESSAGE-CONSUMER] - Consumindo da fila: {}", queue);
        channel.basicConsume(queue, commandConsumer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("[MESSAGE-CONSUMER] - ShutdownException", e);
        shutdownService.shutdown(e);
    }
}
```

### Integration Test Class

```
public class MessageConsumerServiceImplIntegrationTest {

private static final Integer RABBITMQ_PORT = 5672;
private static final String RABBITMQ_EXC = "fcomExcConsumer";
private static final String RABBITMQ_QUEUE = "fcomQueFullcamIntegration";
private static final String RABBITMQ_RK = "fcomRKConsumerFullCam";
private static final String REDIS_PASSWORD = "123456";
private static final int REDIS_PORT = 6379;

public static RabbitMQContainer rabbitMqContainer;
public static GenericContainer redisContainer;

static {
    redisContainer = new GenericContainer<>("redis:5.0.3-alpine")
            .withExposedPorts(REDIS_PORT)
            .withCommand("redis-server --requirepass " + REDIS_PASSWORD)
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());
    redisContainer.start();
}

static {
    rabbitMqContainer = new RabbitMQContainer()
            .withExposedPorts(RABBITMQ_PORT)
            .withExposedPorts(15672)
            .withUser("guest", "guest")
            .withVhost("/")
            .waitingFor(Wait.forListeningPort());
    rabbitMqContainer.start();
}

@Rule
public final EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables = new EnvironmentVariables()
        .set("rabbitmq_host", rabbitMqContainer.getContainerIpAddress())
        .set("rabbitmq_port", String.valueOf(rabbitMqContainer.getMappedPort(RABBITMQ_PORT)))
        .set("rabbitmq_virtual_host", "/")
        .set("rabbitmq_username", "guest")
        .set("rabbitmq_password", "guest")

        .set("rabbitmq_fullcam_host", rabbitMqContainer.getContainerIpAddress())
        .set("rabbitmq_fullcam_port", String.valueOf(rabbitMqContainer.getMappedPort(RABBITMQ_PORT)))
        .set("rabbitmq_fullcam_virtual_host", "/")
        .set("rabbitmq_fullcam_username", "guest")
        .set("rabbitmq_fullcam_password", "guest")

        .set("rabbitmq_publish_fullcam_queue", "Fullarm.Request")
        .set("rabbitmq_publish_fullcam_exc", "fcomExcFullcam")
        .set("rabbitmq_publish_fullcam_rk", "fcomRKFullcamRequest")

        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_queue", RABBITMQ_QUEUE)
        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_exc", RABBITMQ_EXC)
        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullarm_rk", RABBITMQ_RK)

        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_queue", "Fullarm.Reponse")
        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_exc", "fcomExcFullarm")
        .set("rabbitmq_consumer_fullcam_rk", "fcomRKFullarmFullcamIntegration")

        .set("f_infra_rabbit_host", "abobora")
        .set("f_infra_exchange", "abobora")
        .set("f_infra_queue", "abobora")
        .set("f_infra_process_id", "0")
        .set("f_infra_description", "abobora")
        .set("f_infra_text", "abobora")
        .set("f_infra_tag", "0")
        .set("f_infra_warning_time", "0")
        .set("f_infra_critical_time", "0")
        .set("f_infra_run", "false")
        .set("f_infra_ka_time", "1")

        .set("redis_host", redisContainer.getContainerIpAddress())
        .set("redis_port", String.valueOf(redisContainer.getMappedPort(REDIS_PORT)))
        .set("redis_password", REDIS_PASSWORD);

private MessageConsumerService instance;
private ApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringInfraConfig.class);
    instance = context.getBean(MessageConsumerService.class);
}

@Test
public void deveProcessarRequisicao() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    String message = "{ \"tipoPacote\" : 3, \"descricao_painel\" : \"Casa Mauro Naves\", \"setor_disparado\" : \"Porta da Frente\", \"data_disparo\" : 1587151300000, \"cameras\" : [90851, 90853, 90854] }";

    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    RabbitMQSettings settings = context.getBean(RabbitMQSettings.class);
    factory.setHost(settings.getConnectionInfo().getHost());
    factory.setPort(settings.getConnectionInfo().getPort());
    factory.setVirtualHost(settings.getConnectionInfo().getVirtualHost());
    factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    factory.setUsername(settings.getConnectionInfo().getUsername());
    factory.setPassword(settings.getConnectionInfo().getPassword());
    factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(50);
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();

    RabbitQueueInfo commandQueInfo = settings.getRabbitMQFullArmConsumerQueue();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
    channel.exchangeDeclare(commandQueInfo.getExchange(), "direct", true);
    channel.queueDeclare(commandQueInfo.getQueue(), true, false, false, null);
    channel.queueBind(commandQueInfo.getQueue(), commandQueInfo.getExchange(), commandQueInfo.getRoutingKey());
    channel.basicPublish(commandQueInfo.getExchange(), commandQueInfo.getRoutingKey(), MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, message.getBytes());
    channel.close();
    connection.close();

    instance.startListening();

}
```

### Gradle depencies

#### core-build.gradle

```
dependencies {

   compile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
   compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.2.5.RELEASE'

   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.1'
   compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.1-1'

   compile group: 'br.com.fulltime.fullarm', name: 'cross-cutting-commons', version: '1.13.0'
   compile group: 'br.com.fulltime.fullarm', name: 'constants', version: '1.110.0'
}
```

#### infra-build.gradle

```
dependencies {

   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
   testCompile "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.14.1"
   testCompile "org.testcontainers:rabbitmq:1.14.1"
   testCompile group: 'com.github.stefanbirkner', name: 'system-rules', version: '1.19.0'


   compile project(':core')

   compile group: 'br.com.fulltime.fullarm', name: 'infrastructure-commons', version: '1.6.0'
   compile group: 'br.com.fulltime.fullarm', name: 'FInfraJavaLibrary', version: '2.3.0'
   compile group: 'br.com.fulltime.fullarm', name: 'pushover-lib', version: '1.0.0'

   compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '3.3.0'
}
```

#### Test output

```
Testing started at 08:38 ...
Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 815 ms
> Task :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :core:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :core:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :infra:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :infra:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :infra:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :infra:compileTestJava
> Task :infra:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :infra:testClasses
> Task :infra:test
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables (file:/home/*omited*/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.stefanbirkner/system-rules/1.19.0/d541c9a1cff0dda32e2436c74562e2e4aa6c88cd/system-rules-1.19.0.jar) to field java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.m
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2020-05-14 08:38:35 INFO - [MESSAGE-CONSUMER] - Consumindo da fila: fcomQueFullcamIntegration
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.junit.contrib.java.lang.system.EnvironmentVariables
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access     operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 22s
5 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 3 up-to-date
08:38:36: Task execution finished ':infra:test --tests     "br.com.fulltime.fullarm.fullcam.integration.infra.consumer.MessageConsumerServiceImplIntegrationTest.deveProcessarRequisicao"'.
```

I have no more idea about the problema. Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance

## UPDATE

I wrote my test again making it simplier. I wrote one code with Spring-context and env stuff and another one without Spring-context and env stuff. BOTH DIDN'T worked.

So, for testing porpuse I coded a simple `Thread#sleep()` and guess what, BOTH tests worked!

I think the cause is the RabbitMQ DefaultConsumer instanciate a new Thread for consuming messages, what releases the main testing Thread and it got stoped. Since main Thread has been stoped all others get stopped too.

So I think we got a synchronism test problem here.

#### It's possible to get a failing test if the test code checks database value which should be inserted in exection but in the checking time it was not processed yet?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you don't have any logging enabled so it's hard to say what is really going on.

Is Spring Boot an option for you? It has built-in logging support. Or are you using just *context library on purpose?

Comment: I'm not used to SpringBoot, I was using Guice for dependency injection, but then I changed to Spring-context for easy use. 
About the logging, the output error is about another property library which I'm not providing an log implementation. But my own code uses Log4J, which you can see in this line : *2020-05-14 08:38:35 INFO - [MESSAGE-CONSUMER] - Consumindo da fila: fcomQueFullcamIntegration*